# Return zeros in empty query result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    --DGC.Name
    [GameChannel], 
    SUM([AdjustedGames] ) *100. / SUM(SUM([AdjustedGames])) OVER()  [Percentage]
FROM #GameChannelResults1 GC
--LEFT OUTER JOIN [WarehouseMgmt].[DimGameChannel] DGC ON DGC.Name = GC.[GameChannel]
GROUP BY [GameChannel]--DGC.Name
```

But when there is no match it returns empty result(nothing).I want to put somehow all values from [WarehouseMgmt].[DimGameChannel].Name as GameChannel and 0 for percentage if there is no match or result is empty. How i can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this, JOIN to your dimension, like you already had commented.

```
    SELECT 
        DGC.Name
        ISNULL(SUM([AdjustedGames] ) *100. / SUM(SUM([AdjustedGames])) OVER(),0)  [Percentage]
    FROM [WarehouseMgmt].[DimGameChannel] DGC
    LEFT JOIN #GameChannelResults1 GC ON DGC.Name = GC.[GameChannel]
    GROUP BY DGC.Name
```

Comment: thank you, that helps. RIGHT JOIN and ISNULL was the solution

Answer (score 0):

It always helps if you add sample data to your question, and provide the expected output.  SO has a [handy guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on this topic, you might want to read.

This sample has three channels.  Two of those channels have results, one does not.

**Sample**

```
-- Table vars are easy to share.
DECLARE @Channel TABLE
    (
        ChannelName     VARCHAR(10)
    )
;

DECLARE @GameResults TABLE
    (
        ChannelName     VARCHAR(10),
        AdjustedGames   INT
    )
;

-- There are three sample channels...
INSERT INTO @Channel 
    (
        ChannelName
    )
VALUES
    ('Channel A'),
    ('Channel B'),
    ('Channel C')
;

-- ... but only two contain results.
INSERT INTO @GameResults
    (
        ChannelName,
        AdjustedGames
    )
VALUES
    ('Channel A', 1),
    ('Channel A', 2),
    ('Channel B', 1),
    ('Channel B', 2)
;
```

**Query**

This query uses an [outer join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208894(v=office.12).aspx) to return every record from the `@Channel` table and any matching records from the `@GameResults` table.  When there are no matching records NULL is returned by default.  I've used [ISNULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms184325.aspx) to replace these with a 0.

```
-- Outer join example.
SELECT
    c.ChannelName,
    ISNULL(SUM(AdjustedGames), 0)   AS AdjustedGames
FROM
    @Channel AS c
        LEFT OUTER JOIN @GameResults AS gr      ON gr.ChannelName = c.ChannelName
GROUP BY
    c.ChannelName
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

Use `NULLIF` function.
It works like `CASE`, if value is blank then returns null ...

```
NULLIF(Value,'')
```

Then you can use `ISNULL` to replace `NULL` values with `0`.

Use together to tweak your desired logic ...